# TSQL change rows into a merged column

Tags: t-sql, merge

I have a table from which I'm trying to merge rows into one column.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally I want to be ale to join this script to another script.

The column I need to merge is SignificantFindings based on ActionRef. I Have attached an image of sample data.

```
SELECT        ID, ResultId, SyncDate, JobNo, ActionRef, ActionStatus, DateFirRiskIdentified, AssessNo, ActionDueDate, DescFirRiskRequired, SignificantFindings, PriorityRisk, FirRiskInternalExternal, AreaLocRisk, 
                         FloorFirRisk, AddLocRiskInfo, FurtherControlReq, Officer
FROM            CYHSQL01.TM_FireRiskAssessment.dbo.ActionRequired
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please do not post data as an image. The volunteers you are asking for help from cannot use it. Please, at a minimum, supply the data as tabular formatted `text`, or (even better) as DDL and DML statements. Please also show us what the expected results are for your well formatted sample data is. Many thanks.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and not pictures.

Answer (score 1):

For your next question: Please do not post pictures.

Best was a MCVE. In this case I do this for you. Please try to set up such a test scenario on your own for the next occasion. The goal is, to have a *stand alone sample* to reproduce your issue with your own attempts and the expected result:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ActionRef VARCHAR(100),SignificantFindings VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('AR1','Finding ar1.1')
                              ,('AR1','Finding ar1.2')
                              ,('AR2','Finding ar2.1');

SELECT ar.ActionRef
      ,STUFF(
       (
        SELECT CONCAT(', ', ar2.SignificantFindings)
        FROM @mockupTable ar2
        WHERE ar2.ActionRef=ar.ActionRef
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS ConcatenatedFindings
FROM @mockupTable ar
GROUP BY ar.ActionRef;
```

Starting with v2017+ there is `STRING_AGG()`

```
SELECT ar.ActionRef
      ,STRING_AGG(ar.SignificantFindings,';') AS ConcatenatedFindings
FROM @mockupTable ar
GROUP BY ar.ActionRef;
```

With your own table name this will be close to something along this:

```
SELECT ar.ActionRef
      ,STUFF(
       (
        SELECT CONCAT(', ', ar2.SignificantFindings)
        FROM CYHSQL01.TM_FireRiskAssessment.dbo.ActionRequired ar2
        WHERE ar2.ActionRef=ar.ActionRef
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS ConcatenatedFindings
FROM CYHSQL01.TM_FireRiskAssessment.dbo.ActionRequired ar
GROUP BY ar.ActionRef;
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will avoid posting images next time. How do I add the ResultId to this query as I need that to join to another query.

Comment: @user3306489 I cannot know this as I don't know your data and tables. Please close this - if solved - by accepting the answer and by up-voting it and then start a new question. Use my mcve and add your other data. Try to set up a *stand-alone* sample as above.